# Filters order is different between dev and test (devise + cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm facing different behaviors in dev and test environment using devise and cancan.

I'm using :

- rails 3.2.2
- cancan 1.6.7
- devise 2.0.4
- capybara 1.1.2

I've got a controller :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit]
  authorize_resource
  ...show, edit...
```

With

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
```

My test is :

- go the home page
- open products list
- open 1 product
- edit this product

Translated using capybara :

```
scenario "test" do
  visit("/");
  click_link("Products")
  click_link("Awesome Product 00001")
  puts current_url
  click_link("Edit")
  puts current_url
  save_and_open_page
end
```

When I do this in dev mode in my browser, I end up on the sign in page as expected and the console prints:

```
http://www.example.com/products/1
http://www.example.com/users/sign_in
```

But when running my spec, I got a 403 with:

```
http://www.example.com/products/1
http://www.example.com/products/1/edit
```

If I use `prepend_before_filter` instead of `before_filter`, it's working... So it appears that's a problem with filter ordering. I manage to print this:

```
403 ===>
[:verify_authenticity_token, "_callback_after_83(self)", "_callback_before_231(self)", "_callback_before_299(self)", :authenticate_user!, "_callback_after_309(self)", :set_locale, :set_mailer_options, :store_location]

prepend_before_filter ===>
[:verify_authenticity_token, :authenticate_user!, "_callback_after_83(self)", "_callback_before_231(self)", "_callback_before_299(self)", "_callback_after_309(self)", :set_locale, :set_mailer_options, :store_location]

in browser ===>
[:verify_authenticity_token, "_callback_before_5", "_callback_after_245(self)", :set_locale, :set_mailer_options, :store_location, :authenticate_user!, "_callback_before_305(self)"]
```

I searched the web for filter ordering, but was unable to find anything related to devise and cancan (and very few about filter ordering in general).
I'm not satisfied with the prepend solution since there may be a bigger problem lying around... Have someone a clue about this behaviour?

thanks

**EDIT**

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    # The ability rules further down in a file will override a previous one.
    # See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence

    default_abilities

    if user.role_member?
      member_abilities
    end

    if user.role_client?
      client_abilities
    end

    if user.role_administrator?
      administrator_abilities
    end
  end

  # ------------------------------------
  private

  # define abilities for everyone, including guests
  def default_abilities
    can :index, :home
    can :read, Product
    can [:read, :subcategories], ProductCategory
  end

  # define abilities for administrators
  def administrator_abilities
  end

  # define abilities for clients
  def client_abilities
    can :edit, Product
  end

  # define abilities for members
  def member_abilities
    can :read, Member
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you check if the user you use to sign in can edit the product with the id =1 ? I think this may be the problem with cancan. Could you post the ability model here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I edited my question to add the Ability class.

Comment: Does the user who you want to edit the product have the client role ?